# gdb-multiarch for RHEL

Tags: linux, gdb, arm, qemu

I am trying to find away to run the **gdb-multiarch** command in RHEL. I have installed the QEMU emulator for ARM processing. I want to install the GDB for debugging. I am able to install the **GDB-multiarch** successfully in Ubuntu by running the command

```
sudo apt-get GDB-multiarch
```

However, I do not find **yum install GDB-multiarch**. If I run the command GDB in RHEL, I am getting the shell prompt for GDB. However, if I run the command gdb-multiarch, I get a "command not found" error. I do realize the repository for gdb-multiarch is not available with RHEL. I tried different versions of GDB from [this](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) link. I do see the multiarch is supported in 7.6.1 version from [this](http://oswatershed.org/pkg/gdb-multiarch) link. However, I still get the command not found error only.  I have raised a question regarding this problem in unix stack exchange. The link to that question is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92073/gdb-multiarch-command-not-found) one.

Can someone please let me know if the gdb-multiarch is supported in RHEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe RHEL includes a multiarch gdb package.  You can report a feature request to Red Hat bugzilla in the usual way, or contact your TAM if you have one.  Alternatively, you can build gdb yourself.

Comment: Hi Tom, I appreciate your help in answering my query. I mailed the bugzilla saying this feature is not supported in RHEL. This is the link to my raised query. https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15976

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but I just encountered this problem and found a solution. First of all, as mentioned, the gdb-multiarch package is available in Debian distributions but not in RHEL (the current version is RHEL 9) until now. I am using RHEL 7 and the solution below is valid for RHEL 7, but you can find a solution for other RHEL versions by installing similar packages.

1. install **devtoolset-11**(If you can't find devtoolset-11 with yum, you can download it directly from this [***link***](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/devtoolset-11-11.0-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html))
2. If you have previously installed an older gdb package, you need to activate the devtoolset-11 gdb version. To do this, run the "`scl enable devtoolset-11 bash`" command
3. Check the gdb version with "`gdb -v`". Result should be ;

> "GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 10.2-6.el7
>
> Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc."

4. Start the gdb session with the "`gdb`" command
5. Run the command to connect remote target :"`target remote localhost:1234`"
6. If you don't get an error, you are ready to debug.