# gdbserver: Target description specified unknown architecture "aarch64"

Tags: debugging, arm, gdbserver

I try to use remotely the gdbserver for debug as follows

Start the gdbserver on target machine

```
$ gdbserver localhost:2000 hello -l 20 -b 10 --enable-targets=all
```

Host machine has the program binary with debugging enabled

```
"copied binary from ARM target to host"
```

Run gdb on host machine

```
$ gdb -q --args hello --enable-target=all
```

Connect to the target

```
(gdb) target remote 192.168.15.132
192.168.15.132: No such file or directory.
(gdb) target remote 192.168.15.132:2000
Remote debugging using 192.168.15.132:2000
warning: while parsing target description (at line 11): Target description specified unknown architecture "aarch64"
warning: Could not load XML target description; ignoring
Remote register badly formatted: T051d:0000000000000000;1f:80fcffffffff0000;20:403cfdb7ffff0000;thread:pd60.d60;core:1;
here: 00000000;1f:80fcffffffff0000;20:403cfdb7ffff0000;thread:pd60.d60;core:1;
(gdb) q
```

I am looking for an advice to correctly debug with ARM remote target.

Comment: Could you please provide the outputs for the five following commands: 1) on the target machine: "uname -a" , "gdbserver --version" , "file hello" 2) on the host machine: "uname -a" and "gdb --configuration" - please use the paths to the exact versions of gdbserver, gdb and hello you are using.

Comment: 1) uname -a
Linux imx8qmmek 4.9.51-8qm_beta2_8qxp_beta+g423d942 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Sep 18 14:49:17 CEST 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux,

Comment: 1) gdbserver --version
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.
This gdbserver was configured as "aarch64-poky-linux"

Comment: 1) ~/test1# file hello
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.14.0, BuildID[sha1]=800749f3ba9f83a96e4b47d6973d5139312409e8, not stripped
root@imx8qmmek:~/test1#

Comment: 2) uname -a
Linux ubuntu-Latitude-7480 4.15.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 17:09:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: 2) ~/work/test1$ which gdb
/usr/bin/gdb
gdb --configuration
configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
--with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
--with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
--with-expat
--with-gdb-datadir=/usr/share/gdb (relocatable)
--with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/lib/gdb (relocatable)
--without-libunwind-ia64
--with-lzma
--with-python=/usr (relocatable)
--without-guile
--with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug (relocatable)
--with-system-gdbinit=/etc/gdb/gdbinit
--with-babeltrace

Comment: ./home/root/test1/hello; /usr/bin/gdbserver ; /usr/bin/gdb

Comment: gdb on host side is not providing aarch64, (gdb) set architecture 
auto               i386:x64-32        i386:x86-64:intel
i386               i386:x64-32:intel  i386:x86-64:nacl
i386:intel         i386:x64-32:nacl   i8086
i386:nacl          i386:x86-64        
(gdb) set architecture

Answer (score 23):

To debug executables compiled for a different architecture, install `gdb-multiarch` and run `gdb-multiarch` instead of `gdb`. Different distributions compile gdb differently and some even lack the multiarch version in their repositories - [RHEL doesn't include it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968584/gdb-multiarch-for-rhel), but it's present in Ubuntu and Debian.

Comment: This is the right answer. gdbserver running on aarch64 and gdb-multiarch from ubuntu.  sudo apt-get install -y gdb-multiarch

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reporting that your GDB supports the following architectures:
`i386:x64-32 i386:x86-64:intel i386 i386:x64-32:intel i386:x86-64:nacl i386:intel i386:x64-32:nacl i8086 i386:nacl i386:x86-64`, you may be attempting to remotely debug an aarch64-linux-gnu executable using an x86_64-targeted version of gdb.I would suggest to download/install [gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz):

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz
tar Jxvf  gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz -C /opt
```

and then use `/opt/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb` for remotely debugging your program.

Comment: wget URL didn't worked for me but this 7.5 version worked 
gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz